# Permission denied: .htaccess pcfg_openfile

Tags: .htaccess, permissions

I'm a programmer with very little knowledge of website administration. I've inherited the task of uploading our new pages and data to our website. I have a sandbox site that works great, and I've transferred everything for that site to the live site. Now I get 403 in the browser, and the only clue I've been able to find so far is in one of the error logs: `Permission denied: .htaccess pcfg_openfile`. But both the old and new .htaccess files have 0644 permissions, and both parent directories have 0750 permissions. I don't know where to go from here. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parent from `750` to `755`.

Update. Then try this from a shell prompt.

```
chmod -R 755 /path/to/siteroot/
```

Comment: I tried it, but no joy. Note that the old parent has 0750 and it works fine.

Comment: BTW are you using a control panel of some sort?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using cpanel. I had the same idea you mention, using chmod and chown, but I can't figure out how to get a terminal window. I tried using ssh, but I got "connection refused". Any thoughts on how to get a shell?

Comment: You may not have access if you're on shared hosting. Change the permission of parent with ftp and select recursive option.

Comment: D'oh! Realized I could do it locally and re-upload the files. Works great now. Not sure which files actually need 0755, but I can experiment to find out. Thanks much for the help.

Comment: No problem. 0755 is for directories/folders, regular files should have 0644. Which is good for security. Glad you go it working.